Power Automate to import list items into SharePoint, difficulty getting a multi-value lookup column to work
I have an excel template that will be used to import list items into SharePoint. One column in SharePoint is a multi-value Lookup column. I'm having trouble importing multiple values from excel into the lookup column in Sharepoint.
Example in excel: Japan, Brazil
Need this to import into a multi-value lookup column in SharePoint, but am running into issues when I tried a few different ways I found online.
Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Are you using the standard SharePoint connector or doing it via API/HTTP?

I'm using the standard SharePoint connector

You need to know the original list items' ID-s (original: where the Japan and Brazil is located). For example, if the "Japan" is the first and "Brazil" is the second list item, then your xls cell should look like this:
Japan;#1;#Brazil;#2

(you can check it, if you have already some list items in the final list via export into xls)
